# Sitecore Sorting issues

Tags: content-editor

Sitecore version 8.2 Revision 161221

I have an existing site where sorting has been manual for a long time. I have now been requested to switch the sorting of a section within Primary Page Stencil section to be Alpha sorted by display name.

I tried to right click-> Sorting -> Subitems Sorting and setting it to Display Name then clicking reset and okay.

However once I do this and I insert a new item under the parent, it adds the item as the last child and ignores the sorting I just set.

I do have another Primary Page Stencil section that is working 100% fine without me changing anything, both are built from the same parent template and have the same type of items within them.

Comment: Does the standard value of the item have a sort value predefined?

Comment: Like the template itself? When I add a new item it defaults to 300? I cant find where that 300 is coming from. 

Our workaround right now is to set the entire folder to 300 sort order and it works. But that seems like a workaround not a true fix @MichaelWest

Comment: It's very common for a template to have a "__Standard Values" item configured. On that item default values can be set.

Comment: So i follow the links to the template level. I do see a _SortOrder with a value defined. But the value is 99899 not 300. Interested where that number came from